# Excel Chart Shape doesn't apply

Tags: excel, vba, charts, shapes

I have an Excel sheet in which a chart is created using VBA. Problem is after generating the chart I set the Shape of it to a built-in Shape style. But when I execute the following code, nothing happens.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("AdoptChart").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("AdoptChart").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("AdoptChart").ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset22
```

When this line is executed `ActiveSheet.Shapes("AdoptChart").ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset22`, the `.ShapeStyle` property doesn't get updated i.e. before this line it was 0 and after executing this line it is still 0.

This was the code which I got by recording macro and manually setting the chart shape style.

I'm using Excel 2010, but the Excel file is a 2003 one (I'm running it in compatibility mode.)

**EDIT:** This is the macro that I got after manually selecting the shape.

```
Sub shape()
'
' shape Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("AdoptChart").ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset22
    Range("I7").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: The most stable Excel version (to me and at least to most that I know) is 2003. Then 2010. So `1.`does your Chart work in 2003 initially? `2.` Are you trying to change `ShapeStyle` of Chart of `Chart DataLabels`? If datalabels, then `ShapeStyle` is not supported. `3.` Can you try to record a macro for the same in a new worksheet and see how it works?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I would suggest you to record a macro for a new Excel 2003 workbook, opened in 2010 in compatible mode. [So you can utilize the 2010 Ribbon as shown in this reference.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/excel-help/change-the-layout-or-style-of-a-chart-HA010342249.aspx#BMquickformat) However it's **very important to know which version of Excel you are intending to use these Charts going forward**. Is it going to be in 2010 or 2003..as `ShapeStyle` is added in 2007...

> `2`. On the Format tab, do one of the following:
>
> In the Current Selection group, click Format Selection, and then in the Format  dialog box, select the formatting options that you want. In the Shape Styles group, click the More button Button image, and then select a style.

**Excel Ribbon Image:**

[image]

> In the Shape Styles group, click Shape Fill, Shape Outline, or Shape Effects and then select the formatting options that you want.

[Check on this article in John Peltier's site](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/programming-excel-2007-2010-autoshapes-with-vba/) , the code comparison between 2007, 2003 is very informative. So why don't you **SAVE AS WORKBOOK INTO EXCEL 2010**?

```
Sub FormatConnector2003(oConnector As Shape)
  With oConnector
    If .Connector Or .Type = msoLine Then
      ' rough approximation of the Excel 2007 preset line style #17
      .Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
      .Line.Weight = 2
      .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 80, 77)
      .Shadow.Type = msoShadow6
      .Shadow.IncrementOffsetX -4.5
      .Shadow.IncrementOffsetY -4.5
      .Shadow.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 192, 192)
      .Shadow.Transparency = 0.5
      .Visible = msoTrue
    End If
  End With
End Sub

Sub FormatConnector2007(oConnector As Shape)
  With oConnector
    If .Connector Or .Type = msoLine Then
      .Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
      .ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset17
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It is going to be 2010 (but since I had issues in fully converting it to 2010, therefore I"m running it in compatibility mode.) Please see EDIT.

Comment: The code you provided, doesn't set msoShapeStylePreset22 rather msoLineStylePreset17. The reason I'm not saving it as 2010 is that an add-in doesn't work if I convert it to 2010 version.

Comment: The code I provided is just a demo sample. Just to show you a direction. Not the exact code :) If your add-in doesn't work in 2010, is there anyway you can check with the add-in owner if it could support 2010, since you are going to use 2010 all the way?

Comment: It is an in-house developed add-in and the developers are out of contact, so that is not an option.